# Blogname ORDER BY id ASC

Tags: php, wordpress

I want all bloglist and the blogname sort on ASC. I have now all blog but how can blogname sort on ASC?

```
<?php 
$blog_list = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );
krsort($blog_list);
foreach ($blog_list as $blog)

{$blogname = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM wp_".$blog['blog_id'] ."_options WHERE option_name='blogname'");
foreach ($blogname as $name) {
echo '<li class="menu-item">';
echo '<a href="'.$blog['path'].'">'.$name->option_value.'</a>';
echo '</li>';}}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it simply add ORDER BY at the end of your query.

```
$blogname = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM wp_".$blog['blog_id'] ."_options WHERE option_name='blogname' ORDER BY option_name ASC");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: I modified the code but still not on ASC:
             <?php 
     $blog_list = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );
     krsort($blog_list);
     foreach ($blog_list as $blog)
     
     {      
      $blogname = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM wp_".$blog['blog_id'] ."_options WHERE option_name='blogname' ORDER BY option_name ASC");
      foreach ($blogname as $name) {
       echo '<li class="menu-item">';
       echo '<a href="'.$blog['path'].'">'.$name->option_value.'</a>';
       echo '</li>';
      }
     }

    ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your query just a touch:

```
{$blogname = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM wp_".$blog['blog_id'] ."_options WHERE option_name='blogname' ORDER BY option_name ASC");
```